# c3 failed to parse when using .toString()

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

There is a similar question mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642089/c3-js-timeseries-with-time-fails-to-parse), however, it doesn't solve my problem. A trivial `c3` script fails to load data when using `.toString()` method on `var dates = ["2015-03-07", "2015-03-09"]`

```
data: {
    x: 'x',
    xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x'
    columns: [
        ['x', dates.toString()],
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]
    ]
},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
            format: '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? The error is as follows

```
Failed to parse x '2015-03-07,2015-03-09' to Date object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toString` turns the array into one string, use this  in the columns property instead

```
['x'].concat(dates),
```